# Why layer shifting prints on Ender 3 Pro?

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality, layer-shifting, overextrusion

Prints on an Ender 3 Pro using a standard printing profile results in layer shifting or over extrusion.  I can’t figure out what the problem is.  I tried reducing the flow as well as print speed but nothing really changes. Any thoughts on the  XYZ cube test print below?

[image: 3D printed calibration cube with printing errors]

Comment: Have you checked belt tension?

Comment: Thanks.  I checked my belts and x axis was very loose.

Comment: Does your prints over adhere or ooze with all filaments? I've found different filaments needing quite different heats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't what folks usually refer to as "layer shifts" - those are generally permanent (for the rest of the print) and don't correct unless you get an equal opposite-direction shift, and are caused by things like a stepper motor skipping a step, a belt skipping a tooth, or the print surface shifting on the bed.

Your problem looks more like excess play in the positioning, particularly on the X axis, likely due to a very loose belt. If so, it will manifest differently in different layers due to the geometry and the last direction of motion.

It's also possible that it's Z wobble, where the toolhead experiences a Z-coordinate-dependent displacement in the X and Y directions due to irregularities in the Z motion system. This could be a bent or nicked lead screw or nut, flat spots or other damage to the V roller wheels, or debris on the aluminum V slot extrusions that the V wheels are rolling on.

The fact that the top layer came out very clean and consistent makes me actually suspect it's the latter - some sort of Z wobble.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed comment.  Tightening the Z axis belt removed most of the print issues however there seems to be another issue where the print is over-adhered to the stock flexible print bed.  This also results in the first layers oozing out.  Kind of apparent in the provided picture but not as much as other prints.

Comment: Marking this as correct answer because it was detailed and in the answer format. Didn’t take care of 100% but about 90% of issues.